# Catch id child's element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I loaded up some image:

```
<div id="cont-img">
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/1.png" id="v1" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/2.png" id="v2" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/3.png" id="v3" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/4.png" id="v4" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/5.png" id="v5" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/6.png" id="v6" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/7.png" id="v7" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/8.png" id="v8" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/9.png" id="v9" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/10.png" id="v10" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/11.png" id="v11" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/12.png" id="v12" />
    <img class="lista-img" src="list/13.png" id="v13" />
</div>
```

and I make it invisible with 'display:none'

I insert 8 images of these in a table:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr id="riga-img">
        <td class="td-img" id="iv1"></td>
        <td class="td-img" id="iv2"></td>
        <td class="td-img" id="iv3"></td>
        <td class="td-img" id="iv4"></td>
        <td class="td-img" id="iv5"></td>
        <td class="td-img" id="iv6"></td>
        <td class="td-img" id="iv7"></td>
        <td class="td-img" id="iv8"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I catch the id of image that lying in a td?
I make this:

```
$("#riga-img td").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).child().attr('id');
```

but it doesn't run.

Comment: If you need `Id` of all images, use `.children().each()` and then `this.id`. `.child()` is not a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("#riga-img td").click(function(){ var id=$(this).attr('id');})
```

EDIT:

Answer:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/pv1ngb7m

Comment: return td's id. I want image's id.

Comment: How about this?
`$("#riga-img td").click(function(){ var id=$(this).children('img').attr('id');})`
If this didn't work. Please create a JS fiddle and share.

Comment: You have not specified id for your image's. See my updated fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/pv1ngb7m/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- If your inner element is `<img>`

  ```
  var id = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
  ```
- If your inner element is `<td>`

  ```
  var id = $(this).find('td.td-img').attr('id');
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
$('#riga-img').on('click', 'img', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```